# How do I properly refer to the stones weight in this code?

Tags: java

How do I refer to the stones weight in this code, so I can use it in my unlockChest method? I'm basically trying to add up the weight the user inputs from the object new Stone()) so it == combination the user inputs in the Chest() constructor. I know this is wrong but I tried jar1.weight, and it says it's not a variable.

```java
public class Stone
{

    private String name;
    private int weight;

    public Stone()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter stone name: ");
        name = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter stone weight: ");
        weight = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
        Global.keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}


public class Jar
{

    private int position;
    private Stone stone;


    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)
    {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

public class Ground
{
    private Jar jar1;
    private Jar jar2;
    private Jar jar3;
    private Player player;
    private Chest chest;

    public Ground()
    {
      player = new Player();

      jar1 = new Jar(1, new Stone());
      jar2 = new Jar(2, new Stone());
      jar3 = new Jar(3, new Stone());

      chest = new Chest()

    }

    public boolean ChestUnlocked()
    {
        if (jar1.weight + jar2.weight + jar3.weight == chest.combination) //the main problem
         return true;
        else
         return false;
    }


public class Chest
{

    public int combination;
    private int position;
    private Jar jar1;
    private Jar jar2;
    private Jar jar3;

    public Chest()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter chest combination (5-10): ");
        combination = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
        Global.keyboard.nextLine();


        position = 4;
        jar1 = new Jar(4, null);
        jar2 = new Jar(4, null);
        jar3 = new Jar(4, null);
    }
```

Comment: Your Jar class doesn't have a .weight property, only your Stone class does.  If you want to compute the weight of the jar based on the weight of the stones it contains, you will have to write that logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Stone and probably, the weight attribute in the Stone class are private. In order to use them correctly I would recommend you to implement the getter methods for your classes. After you implemented the getters you can call them with something like :

```
jar1.getStone().getWeigth()
```

Where getStone() is the getter inside the Jar class and getWeight() is the getter inside the Stone class.

Comment: keep in mind - this is against [Demeter law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: 
Add getters / setters in each of your classes so you can access your private variables using getters and setters.

Stone() is a private object in Jar(). Supposing you have getStone() in Jar() that returns: this.stone;  you can do

```
if (jar1.getStone().getWeight() + jar2.getStone().getWeight() + jar3.getStone().getWeight() == chest.combination) //the main problem
```

Also make sure that you check for null objects before trying to access a method in a nullable object (e.g. jar1.getStone().getWeight() will fail if jar1 stone is null)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the weight in `Stone` public by adding a getter

```
public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

Then you can use that in a similiar method in `Jar`

```
public int getWeight() {
    if (stone == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return stone.getWeight();
}
```

Then your method would be

```
public boolean ChestUnlocked() {
    if (jar1.getWeight() + jar2.getWeight() + jar3.getWeight() == chest.combination) {
         return true;
    }
     return false;
}
```

assuming the Jar objects and Chess object are never null